# Unique Key Constraint Check In Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework

I have a unique key constraint in my SQL Server that is based on two columns (AbsoluteCounter, TimeMfrAudit).  If I try to add a list of objects via Entity Framework, how can I check if one of my objects is going to violate this constraint without throwing an exception that will make my entire context.SaveChanges() fail ?  I am looking for a best practice here.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These would be all objects that violate the unique key constraint:

```
var violatingObjects = listOfObjectsToAdd
    .Where(o => context.Objects.Any(oInDb =>
        oInDb.AbsoluteCounter == o.AbsoluteCounter &&
        oInDb.TimeMfrAudit == o.TimeMfrAudit))
    .ToList();
```

It is one `EXISTS` database query per object in the list. If you only want to know the first object that violates the constraint use `FirstOrDefault()` instead of `ToList()`. If you only want to know if there is any violating object at all use `Any()` instead of `ToList()`. The iteration should stop when the first object has been found.